# appending arguments to a String

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, arguments, stringbuilder

I need to write a simple Java program so as to step through a given string (given from args[]), and receive a println once a certain character (e.g. '^') is encountered. However, I cannot find why I cannot receive such println. Could you please check what is the stem of the error?

```
public class JavaApplication15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer copyFromMe = null;
        for (int j = args.length; --j<=0; ) {
            copyFromMe = new StringBuffer();
            copyFromMe.append(args[j]);
        } 

        StringBuffer copyToMe = new StringBuffer();

        int i = 0;
        char c = copyFromMe.charAt(i);
        while (c != 'g') {
            copyToMe.append(c);
            c = copyFromMe.charAt(++i);
        }
        System.out.println(copyToMe);
    }

    private static String String(String[] args) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, got it. I rephrased it to suite the potential readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `new StringBuffer` with every iteration of your loop. You should use a `StringBuilder`. And you need to start at `args.length - 1`. Finally `>= 0` like ,

```
StringBuilder copyFromMe = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = args.length - 1; j>=0; j--) {
  // copyFromMe = new StringBuffer();
  copyFromMe.append(args[j]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Elliott. I really appreciate your prompt response. I found that the following is also working:                          for (int j = args.length; --j >= 0 ; )

Comment: @Abraham Yes, that works; but you should [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html). What advantage does using `--j >= 0` have? Also, if you prefer that style why not use `while (--j >= 0)`?

Comment: You're right. The while loop is neater than mine. Thanks for your help.